# sshfs equivalent for windows?

Tags: windows, ssh, nas

At my university, I want to be able to set up a file-server in my room. The only allowed ports/protocols are SSH and RDP. All others are blocked.

I can set up the server just fine, and connect to it with Linux, but can't find a satisfactory way to do it under Windows.

Under Ubuntu I use sshfs to mount a file system through ssh. I want to do the same under Windows. I could use something like Filezilla and do a SFTP connection (which does work). But I was hoping to get something that integrates into the shell.

I found something called Dokan, which is like FUSE for Linux and has a sshfs module. The sshfs part wouldn't install, claiming that the Dokan library was not installed (it was). This was done on a test VM of Windows7.

Any ideas? Preferably solutions would run on Windows 7, with Vista and XP being a bonus.

Comment: Dokan seems like the best solution.  You need to figure out why it's not working.  Have you tried recent versions?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can [tunnel windows file sharing over ssh with putty like so](http://www.blisstonia.com/eolson/notes/smboverssh.php), or any file system for that matter.

Comment: Yea - you can tunnel almost any protocol through SSH. The only difficulty is if the protocol dynamically chooses a port to use, like FTP. That's why they created SFTP. But you shouldn't have any trouble with CIFS/windows file sharing, since it only uses 4 specific ports.

Comment: This is interesting. I have run into the idea of port tunneling before, but you had to disable normal sharing. This idea of using another virtual adaptor is interesting. I will have to give this a shot. I would still prefer a straight up sshfs (or sftp integration), but this is cool.

Answer (score 1):

I use ExpanDrive (http://www.expandrive.com/windows) for this sort of thing, and like it, but it's not free.  ($39.95 for a single user license.)