# How do I map an FTP site to my computer as a drive letter?

Tags: windows, ftp

Is there a way of doing this automagically and reliably?

I know of the feature to add an FTP site as a *Network Location* which then appears in *My Computer*,  but I see no way of assigning a drive letter to it.

It would be a necessity for whatever free software or hack to cache the username and password so it does not have to keep being entered.

My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate, 32 bit, but any suggestions for earlier versions of Windows back to XP would be appreciated too

Comment: Assuming it doesn't matter a lot if SFTP or FTP is used, and though I don't know if any of those mentions drive letters: see also "SFTP as a folder on Vista" at http://superuser.com/questions/55860/sftp-as-a-folder-on-vista and "Mounting SSH/SFTP shares on Windows 7" at http://superuser.com/questions/67551/mounting-ssh-sftp-shares-on-windows-7 (and as an aside: "sshfs equivalent for windows?" at http://superuser.com/questions/40708/sshfs-equivalent-for-windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can with [**NetDrive**](http://www.netdrive.net/) (free for home use):

- Mounts remote storage as a local hard disk on your PC
- Data transfer by drag and drop files in windows explorer
- Able to run files(video, audio and any other .exe files)
- Mounts drive automatically when Windows starts.

Comment: netdrive is no longer free for home use.

Comment: All good things come to an end :-(

Answer (score 1):

DirectNet Drive: Supports FTP, WebDAV, SFTP protocols

DirectNet Drive is free for home use.

http://directnet-drive.net/index.php