# How to share folder in windows XP over internet with password protection

Tags: file-sharing

I am looking for an application I can install in Windows XP to share one of it's directories over Internet with password protection. Ideally I could install it on clients machines so they can use it like regular windows directory. I can't use Dropbox or similar clouds tools because of their license. Is there such application?

Comment: This isn't something I'd generally recommend hooking up directly to the Internet.  You should set up a VPN for something like this, especially if the information on the host system is at all sensitive.

Comment: Is it possible to set a VPN when VPN server is behind NAT?

Comment: With port-forwarding on the router, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to setup an FTP server (assuming your machine is online at the time people need to access the files).  It's password protected and once the clients log in, they will see it like a regular directory with optionally write access.

Start > Control Panel > "Add/Remove Windows Components." > "Windows Components." > "Internet Information Services" > "details" > enable "File Transfer Protocol (FTP)" service.

Follow the instructions for the install Wizard. It may request you to insert your Windows XP CD. The shared directory is "C:\INETPUB\FTPROOT" by default.

Comment: I can set up Filezilla Server, but are there any free apps that maps FTP directory to local file system?

Comment: The directory you would share would already be on the local file system. This question is vague.

Comment: Also, FileZilla is not a server, it is a client...

Comment: FileZilla is both an FTP [Client](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) and [Server](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server). It's actually a very good, easy, free FTP server. ;)

Comment: @PiotrK See [How do I map an FTP site to my computer as a drive letter?](http://superuser.com/questions/96876/how-do-i-map-an-ftp-site-to-my-computer-as-a-drive-letter)