# Mount network drives over ssh on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, sshfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sshfs equivalent for windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/40708/sshfs-equivalent-for-windows)

There is a remote filesystem I can reach through ssh. On Linux, there are several ways of dealing with it. I like `sshfs`, because with it I can work with the remote files the same way as with my local files.

Is there any similar to Windows, that can map a network drive through ssh? The best I can use is `WinSCP`, which is good, but not good enough.

Comment: sshfs is a [Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace).  apparently there are some theoretical Windows equivalents to FUSE, but i don't know of any actual implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SSH there is [Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/).

You could also use WebDAV (which is supported natively by Windows), but it isn't that easy to configure.

Comment: Dokan SSHFS doesn't work for me. I installed the Dokan library, but the Dokan SSHFS installer still says that it is not installed, even after rebooting my computer. Should it run on Windows Vista.

Comment: I succesfully solved the problem.