# Mount SSH resource as normal hard drive under windows

Tags: windows, ssh, mount

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Mount network drives over ssh on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/138341/mount-network-drives-over-ssh-on-windows)
>   [sshfs equivalent for windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/40708/sshfs-equivalent-for-windows)

What is the best method to map an SSH resource to be seen as a hard drive in Windows XP ?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicates: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/55860/sftp-as-a-folder-on-vista), [here](https://superuser.com/questions/40708/sshfs-equivalent-for-windows) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/138341/mount-network-drives-over-ssh-on-windows).

[Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/) works well for me, BTW. Be aware there are some stability issues [reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854424/how-stable-is-dokan-sshfs), mainly on 64-bit.