# Dokan sshfs doesn't stream, has gray Xes

Tags: windows-7, ssh, windows-explorer, video-streaming, sshfs

I installed [Dokan sshfs so I can mount Linux computers as drives in Windows 7 64-bit](https://superuser.com/questions/158893/mount-ssh-resource-as-normal-hard-drive-under-windows-closed).  It seems to work, in the sense that I can view folders and copy files off of it.  However, it doesn't seem like I can stream files, there are no thumbnails, and all the files have gray Xes:

[image]

Are these Xes placed by Dokan or by Windows?  What do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author says:

> Dokan SSHFS adds "offline file attribute" to those files in order to
>   avoid unnecessary
>   network access. You can control it on setting dialog when you mount a drive.

[image: Dokan SSHFS Options dialog]